# React js how to set and get parameter from another file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i'm new in react, and i would like to ask about how to send parameter to another function in class component. For example :

**Main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";
import fetchData from "./Action";

export default class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchingData = this.fetchingData.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      list: 0
    };
  }
  fetchingData(x) {
    const data = fetchData(); // => from Action.js (get the return)
    this.setState({ list: data });
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchingData();        
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h3>Data</h3>
        <Form />
        <p>result: {this.state.list}</p> //=>show the result and auto update when click by button
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**Form.js**

```
import React from "react";
import fetchData from "./Action";

function Form() {
  const handlerClick = (v) => {
    fetchData(v); //=>set value form this function (from action.js)
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={(e) => handlerClick(1)}>Push</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

**Action.js**

```
const fetchData = (v) => {
  return v;
};

export default fetchData;
```

From that code i would like to send parameter from button `handlerClick()` inside of that function, there is `fetchData()`, this function will keep the param and return it to the `Main.js` for fillup the `setState`. And the result will auto updated, when click the button Push.
Would u like to help me fixing my code ?

Comment: Check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4tknz5?file=src%2FMain.js

All you've to do is pass the fetchingData function as a prop to <Form/> and call it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send the function `fetchingData`  as a prop to Form, something like: `<Form fetchingData={fetchingData} />` from Main.js, that way you can call the function from `<Form />` component and have your value saved.

Answer (score 0):

Main.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";
import fetchData from "./Action";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchingData = this.fetchingData.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      list: 0
    };
  }
  fetchingData(x) {
    const data = fetchData(x); // => from Action.js (get the return)
    this.setState({ list: data });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchingData();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h3>Data</h3>
        <Form fData={this.fetchingData} />
        <p>result: {this.state.list}</p>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Form.js

```
import React from "react";
import fetchData from "./Action";

const Form = (props) => {
  const handlerClick = (v) => {
    if (props.fData) {
      props.fData(v);
    } else {
      fetchData(v); //=>set value form this function (from action.js)
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={(e) => handlerClick(10)}>Push</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Action.js

```
const fetchData = (v) => {
  return v;
};

export default fetchData;
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-kepler-hbm9b)